# How to repeat a data flow task for exporting to dynamic Excel file in SSIS 2008?

Tags: dynamic, ssis, export-to-excel

I need to create an SSIS package to export the data from an OLDB source into separate Excel files for each of the 30+ providers and dynamically name the files.

I have successfully created the package using a task-level variable for provider ID to use in the query, package-level variable for provider name to use in the file name and package-level variable for the year to use in both places.

**Q1**: Is there a way to use the column name (name of the provider) for the provider in the expression for destination file name?

**Q2**: Now I need to repeat the task for all our providers. What is a better way than repeat the same data flow task for each of the provider and change the provider ID for each of the tasks and create a separate variable for each of the provider name and change the expression for file name in each of the tasks?

**Q3**: Can I copy the data flow task and change the details? If I do that, then after I execute the task I get an error asking me to run the package as an administrator. What is the best way to copy data flow tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Q1:  Yes, just drag the variable holding the Provider Name into the expression.

Q2:  Use a Loop (for or foreach) and start the loop with a script task that sets the ProviderID variable, and the ProviderName variable (no need to create multiple copies of the variable), and also change the file name in the connection manager.

Q3:  No need to make multiple copies of the dataflow task either.   Just include it in the loop after the script task mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Tab Alleman. ProviderID and ProviderName are two columns in the data. Can I use those to set up the variables? I was actually using a value for a single provider in that variable. Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: Yes, you will start your package with an Execute SQL Task that queries your ProviderId and ProviderName, and then you will loop through those results and populate the variables in the loop.  I don't have sample code handy, but here is a link:  http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop and you can google `ssis foreach loop` for more.

Comment: Thanks Tab Alleman. I will try what you have suggested and explore more. I will get back to you if I have more questions.